# Observing WorkManager Work to get finished Work output

Tags: java, android

I have enqueued a PeriodicWork in WorkManager and want to get its Worker's output data everytime when it's finished but the following code doesn't seem to work as the Log message doesn't appear in Logcat:

```
    WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .getWorkInfoByIdLiveData(MyWork.getId())
            .observe(this, new Observer<WorkInfo>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable WorkInfo workInfo) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onChanged()");
                }
            });
```

is `this` the same as `lifeCycleOwner` ? I have put `this` instead because `lifeCycleOwner` is not recognized here.

Based on [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/intermediate-progress#java) and [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/states-and-observation#java).

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to get the Observer working like this:

```
        WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext())
            .getWorkInfosByTagLiveData(MY_WORK_TAG).
            observeForever(new Observer<List<WorkInfo>>() {
                @Override
                public void onChanged(@Nullable List<WorkInfo> workInfos) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onChanged()");
                    if (workInfos != null && (!(workInfos.isEmpty()))) {
                          for (WorkInfo wI: workInfos) {
                               if (wI.getState() == WorkInfo.State.RUNNING) {
                                      \\ handle workinfo here
                               }
                          }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

> is this the same as lifeCycleOwner ? I have put this instead because lifeCycleOwner is not recognized here.

`this` mean your class you call your code. Actually, when you call `getWorkInfoByIdLiveData` it returns to `LiveData` it means it should be listening in `Android Component` such as `Activity`, `Fragment` ... If your class doesn't implementation `LifecycleOwner` you can use `observeForever` instead of `observe`

Comment: so if `this` is my MainActivity class is it alright ? .. and even with `observeForever` I do not see the log message

Comment: sure, if this is your activity it's ok, I think you don't get log because your work not execute yet

Comment: well my worker does execute. how do I know ? I see the log messages I have put in it and also : `I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result SUCCESS for Work` every time.